# Закрашивать ряд DataGridView

Tags: c#

Необходимо по определённому тексту в dataGridView закрасить весь ряд. У меня получилось только закрасить 1 ячейку. 
Как сделать что бы закрашивался весь ряд?

Мой код ниже.

```
private void Color()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)  
        {  
            for (int j = 0; j< dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)  
        {
                    dataGridView1[j, i].Style.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;  

        switch (dataGridView1[j, i].FormattedValue.ToString().ToLower())  
        {  
            case "удален":
                            dataGridView1[j, i].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;  
                break;


                    }
}  
}  
        }
```

Comment: так лучше будет:
        switch (dataGridView1[j, i].FormattedValue.ToString().ToLower())  
        {  
            case "удален":
                //...
        }

Comment: @bmo спасибо большое, но суть вопроса осталась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1. Нужное нам значение в определенном столбце (к примеру во 2-ом):

```
private void PaintCell()
{           
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)          
   {
     switch (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString())
      {
        case "AAAA":                                                        
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
        default:
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                    break;
      }
  }            
}
```

Вариант 2. Нужное значение в любом столбце

```
private void PaintCell()
{           
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)            
     for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
     {
       switch (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].FormattedValue.ToString())
       {
         case "AAAA":                                                        
                      dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                      break;
        }
      }            
}
```

Comment: это свойство нужно крутить dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor

Comment: @bmo я его уже закрути и в хвост и гриву))

Comment: @Павел получилось хоть?

Comment: @bmo если бы((( я бы тогда написал решение(((

Comment: @MaximK большое тебе спасибо.